# why does a closed subset of a top. n-manifoldis not again a top. n-manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

In the book of *Int. Smooth Manifolds* by Lee, at page 4, it is stated that

> it follows easily from these two exercises that any open subset of a
>   topological n-manifold is itself a topological n-manifold (with the
>   subspace topology, of course).

However, I cannot understand exactly what and how things go wrong when that subset is closed ? i.e why does a closed subset of a top. n-manifoldis not again a top. n-manifold ?

To be clear, the closed subset is again Hausdorff and second countable, but why are they not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n $ locally ?

**Edit:**

I'm looking mainly for a mathematical explanation, rather than only an intuitive one.

Comment: Well, as a start if you choose anything bounded in R^n you get at best a manifold with boundary, not a manifold.

Comment: take a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide yes, it look like it is not the case, intuitively, but I'm looking for a mathematical explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closed disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for instance. No neighborhood of a point $p$ of its boundary is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: can I ask why ? because I'm not comfortable in stating such a thing.

Comment: @onurcanbektas it's just topology. Every open set in R^n about a point p contains a disk about p, and this disk will intersect the exterior. Can you see why this is a problem? (Hint: what must happen to such a neighborhood when we consider the subspace topology by intersecting it with our disk?)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I know topology; but no I can't see why this is a problem  since we are looking that set as in the subspace topology.

Comment: @onurcanbektas what occurs with such a neighborhood is we include part of the boundary, so it is actually homeomorphic to the closed upper half plane (this is the general behavior with manifolds with boundary). Can you think of why the closed upper half plane isn't homeomorphic to R^2?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Right now, I don't see a simple proof. But note that if we have a small neighborhood of $p$, then if we remove from it its intersection with the boundary of the closed disk, what remains *is* homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. But, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if we remove something homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, then what's left is never both connected and simply connected, and therefore it is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sir I'm having trouble in understanding how you formulate your reasoning; it is about the language, not about the mathematics.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen To be honest, no I couldn't; I mean even if we try something like Dr. Santos tried to describe, removing a line or something else from upper half plane, they both would behave the same as far as I can see.

Comment: @onurcanbektas José's argument is definitely sufficient here. You might want to review your topology. What he showed is that our neighborhood cannot be homeomorphic to R^2 since it is instead homeomorphic to R^2 \ R

Comment: @onurcanbektas Consider the closed disk $D\bigl((0,0),1\bigr)$. Its boundary is the circle $C\bigl((0,0),1\bigr)$ centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $1$. Fix $p=(1,0)$ and let $r\in(0,2)$. If $N=D(p,r)\cap D\bigl((0,0),1\bigr)$, then $N$ is a neighborhood of $p$ (in $D\bigl((0,0),1\bigr)$). Now, $N\cap C\bigl((0,0),1\bigr)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ and $N\setminus C\bigl((0,0),1\bigr)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. But if you remove from $\mathbb{R}^2$ a set which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, then you *never* get something homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. I hope that this is better.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, that is definitely better. Thanks  a lot

Comment: @onurcanbektas I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @onurcanbektas let it be noted, the one point example is even easier: any neighborhood is just the point, which is compact, so not homeomorphic to R^n.